# how to make file listing using the .bat script

Tags: batch-file, file-listing

I have directory structure:

```
pakages
|-files.bat
|-component
  |-source
  |-lib
```

I need to make text file using the files.bat script with file listing like this:

```
 File0001=source\WindowT.pas
 File0002=source\AWindowT.pas
 File0003=source\AWindowSplash.pas
 File0004=source\InternalT.pas
 File0005=source\ImageLister.pas
 File0006=lib\LIcons.res
 File0007=lib\TstandartBtn_16.RES
 File0008=lib\TstandartBtn_24.RES
```

......etc

How to make such file listing?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have cobbled together the following script:

```
@echo off
setlocal
rem The number of the current file, gets incremented
set FileNumber=1
rem Move into "component" directory, the following "for" command will 
pushd %~dp0\component
rem loop over directories there
for /d %%f in (*) do call :process "%%f"
rem move into the previous directory again
popd
endlocal
goto :eof

:process
rem process files
for /f %%x in ('dir /b /a:-d %1 2^>nul') do call :process_files %~1 %%x
rem go down recursively, if there are more subdirectories
for /f %%d in ('dir /b /a:+d %1 2^>nul') do call :process %%d
goto :eof

:process_files
call :leadingzeros %FileNumber%
rem Output line
echo File%RESULT%=%~1\%2
set /a FileNumber+=1
goto :eof

rem Parameter: a non-negative number <= 9999
rem Result: a string with zero padding at the start
:leadingzeros
if %1 LSS 10 set RESULT=000%1&goto :eof
if %1 LSS 100 set RESULT=00%1&goto :eof
if %1 LSS 1000 set RESULT=0%1&goto :eof
set RESULT=%1
goto :eof
```

It may be not exactly what you need, but should provide a starting point. The output, however, is identical. For the following file/directory tree:

```
    packages
    │   files.cmd
    │
    └───component
        ├───lib
        │       LIcons.res
        │       TstandardBtn_16.RES
        │       TstandardBtn_24.RES
        │
        └───source
                AWindowSplash.pas
                AWindowT.pas
                ImageLister.pas
                InternalT.pas
                WindowT.pas
```

running the batch will produce the following output:

```
File0001=lib\LIcons.res
File0002=lib\TstandardBtn_16.RES
File0003=lib\TstandardBtn_24.RES
File0004=source\AWindowSplash.pas
File0005=source\AWindowT.pas
File0006=source\ImageLister.pas
File0007=source\InternalT.pas
File0008=source\WindowT.pas
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
dir /A:-D /B /S>out.txt
```

That get's you most of what you want.

Comment: Thanks, but I need loop for generate in the string File0001, File0002 etc And also I need relative path to file
dir /A:-D /B /S>out.txt shows full path

Answer (score 0):

Start with something along the lines of:

```
@echo off

call :dodir .
goto eof

:dodir
set TEMP_CUR_DIR="%*"
REM echo Directory %TEMP_CUR_DIR%:
for %%f in (%TEMP_CUR_DIR%\*) do call :dofile %%f
for /d %%d in (%TEMP_CUR_DIR%\*) do call :dodir %%d
goto eof

:dofile
set TEMP_CUR_FILE="%*"
echo File: %TEMP_CUR_FILE%
goto eof

:eof
```